# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in___

Tags: wordpress, parsing

My site's theme has been working fine for a few days when suddendly without any coding changes I now am getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/henrysst/public_html/wp-content/themes/bettycommerce/includes/pro_framework/admin.php on line 812
```

I have made no changes to the theme, and it was working fine before (Apart from Revolution slider not working)

here is that line that is pulling up the error:

```
} 
add_action('upfw_admin_header_links','upfw_default_header_links');
```

Here is also the link to the site, if its of any help: http://henrysstuff.co.uk/

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

FULL CODE:

```
    <?php

/******
** Pro Bones Framework Version
*************************************/
define('UPTHEMES_VER', '1.0.0');

/******
** Theme init hook
*************************************/
function upfw_theme_init(){
    do_action('upfw_theme_init');
}

/******
** Admin init hook
*************************************/
function upfw_admin_init(){
    do_action('upfw_admin_init');
}

/******
** Initialization adds hooks to
** two places: theme and admin
*************************************/
function upfw_init(){

    if( is_admin() ):
        add_action('after_setup_theme','upfw_admin_init');
    else:
        add_action('after_setup_theme','upfw_theme_init');
    endif;
}

add_action('after_setup_theme','upfw_init',1);

/******
** Set up theme data
*************************************/
function upfw_generate_theme_data(){

    $get_up_theme = get_theme_data(TEMPLATEPATH .'/style.css');
    $theme_title = $get_up_theme['Title'];
    $theme_shortname = strtolower(preg_replace('/ /', '_', $theme_title));
    $theme_version = $get_up_theme['Version'];
    $theme_template = $get_up_theme['Template'];
    define('UPTHEMES_NAME', $theme_title);
    define('TEMPLATENAME', $theme_title);
    define('UPTHEMES_SHORT_NAME', $theme_shortname);
    define('UPTHEMES_THEME_VER', $theme_version);

    if( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH.'/includes/pro_framework/admin.php') ):
        define( 'THEME_PATH' , TEMPLATEPATH );
        define( 'THEME_DIR' , get_template_directory_uri() );
    elseif( file_exists(STYLESHEETPATH.'/includes/pro_framework/admin.php') ):
        define( 'THEME_PATH' , STYLESHEETPATH );
        define( 'THEME_DIR' , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() );
    endif;

    // Detect child theme info
    if(STYLESHEETPATH != TEMPLATEPATH): 
        $get_up_theme = get_theme_data(STYLESHEETPATH .'/style.css');
        $theme_title = $get_up_theme['Title'];
        $theme_shortname = strtolower(preg_replace('/ /', '_', $theme_title));
        $theme_version = $get_up_theme['Version'];
        $theme_template = $get_up_theme['Template'];
        define('CHILD_NAME', $theme_title);
        define('CHILD_SHORT_NAME', $theme_shortname);
        define('CHILD_THEME_VER', $theme_version);
        define('CHILD_PATH', STYLESHEETPATH);
    endif;

}

add_action('upfw_admin_init','upfw_generate_theme_data',1);
add_action('upfw_theme_init','upfw_generate_theme_data',1);

/******
** Upload error msg
*************************************/
function upfw_upload_error(){

    $uploads_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $error = $uploads_dir['error'];
    echo '<div id="message" class="error"><p>' . $error . '</p></div>';
    return false;

}

/******
** Upload folder permissions 
** error msg
*************************************/
function upfw_permissions_error(){

    echo '<div id="message" class="error"><p>' . __('It looks like your uploads folder does not have proper permissions. Please set your uploads folder, typically located at [wp-install]/wp-content/uploads/, to 775 or greater.', MOJO_TEXTDOMAIN) . '</p></div>';
    return false;

}

/******
** Upload folder created 
** success msg
*************************************/
function upfw_uploads_folder_created(){

    $uploads_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $base_upload_dir = $uploads_dir['basedir']."/upfw";

    echo '<div id="message" class="update-nag">' . __('Pro Affiliate Framework uploads folder created successfully! Your new folder is located at '.$base_upload_dir.'.', MOJO_TEXTDOMAIN) . '</div>';
    return false;

}

/******
** Set the uploads directory 
** for media from themes
*************************************/
function upfw_set_uploads_dir(){

    $uploads_dir = wp_upload_dir();

    if( $uploads_dir['error'] )
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'upfw_upload_error', 1, 1 );
    else{

        $base_upload_dir = $uploads_dir['basedir']."/upfw";
        $base_upload_url = $uploads_dir['baseurl']."/upfw";

        if(!is_dir($base_upload_dir) ){

            if( !is_writeable( $uploads_dir['basedir'] ) ) 
                add_action( 'admin_notices', 'upfw_permissions_error', 1, 1 );
            else{
                $oldumask = umask(0);
                @mkdir($base_upload_dir, 0775);
                umask($oldumask);

                if( is_writeable( $base_upload_dir ) )
                    add_action( 'admin_notices', 'upfw_uploads_folder_created',1 , 1 );

            }
        }
    }

    if($base_upload_dir)
        define('UPFW_UPLOADS_DIR',$base_upload_dir, true);

    if($base_upload_url)
        define('UPFW_UPLOADS_URL',$base_upload_url, true);

}

add_action('upfw_theme_init','upfw_set_uploads_dir',2);
add_action('upfw_admin_init','upfw_set_uploads_dir',2);

/******
** Gentlemen, start your engines
*************************************/
function upfw_engines_init(){

    require_once('library/options/options.php');
    require_once('library/widgets/dashboard.php');

    if( !defined('DISABLE_LAYOUT_ENGINE') )
        require_once('library/engines/layout-engine.php');

    if( !defined('DISABLE_STYLE_ENGINE') )
        require_once('library/engines/style-engine.php');

    if(function_exists('upfw_dbwidget_setup'))
            add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'upfw_dbwidget_setup' );

        if(function_exists('default_theme_layouts'))
            add_action('init','default_theme_layouts',1);

}

add_action('upfw_theme_init','upfw_engines_init',10);
add_action('upfw_admin_init','upfw_engines_init',10);

/******
** Conditional to test if we're on
** an Pro Affiliate Framework page
*************************************/
function is_upthemes_page(){

    if(is_admin()):
        if(isset($_REQUEST['page']))$page = $_REQUEST['page'];
        if(!empty($page)):
            if( $page =='proframework' || $page=='proframework-buy' || $page =='proframework-docs' ):
                    return true;
            else:
                    return false;
            endif;
        endif;
    endif;

}

/******
** Add CSS and Javascript includes
*************************************/
function upfw_queue_scripts_styles(){

    $upthemes =  THEME_DIR.'/includes/pro_framework/';

    wp_enqueue_style('up_framework',$upthemes."css/pro_framework.css");

    //Check if theme-options/style.css exists and load it
    if(file_exists(THEME_PATH ."/theme-options/style.css")):
        wp_enqueue_style('theme_options',THEME_DIR."/theme-options/style.css");
    endif;

    wp_enqueue_style('farbtastic');

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.history',
        $upthemes."js/jquery.history.js",
        array('jquery'));

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.color',
        $upthemes."js/jquery.color.js",
        array('jquery'));

    wp_enqueue_script('ajaxupload',
        $upthemes."js/ajaxupload.js",
        array('jquery'));

    wp_enqueue_script('upfw', 
        $upthemes . "js/pro_framework.js", 
        array('farbtastic','jquery.history','ajaxupload'));

    /* For Typography Engine */
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-widget');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-mouse');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-slider', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/includes/pro_framework/js/jquery.ui.slider.js', array('jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-widget', 'jquery-ui-mouse'));
    wp_enqueue_style('up-slider', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/includes/pro_framework/css/ui-themes/smoothness/style.css');

}

if( is_admin() && is_upthemes_page() ):
    add_action('upfw_theme_init','upfw_queue_scripts_styles',40);
    add_action('upfw_admin_init','upfw_queue_scripts_styles',40);
endif;

/******
** Show gallery images
*************************************/
function show_gallery_images(){
    global $wpdb; 

    $theme = THEME_DIR;

    $path = UPFW_UPLOADS_DIR."/";
    $dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open folder. Please make sure your uploads folder exists and has permissions of 775 or greater.");

    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))):

        if($file == "index.php") continue;
        if($file == ".") continue;
        if($file == "..") continue;
        if($file == "list.php") continue;
        if($file == "Thumbs.db") continue;
        $list .= '<a class="preview" href="'. UPFW_UPLOADS_URL . "/". $file . '"><img src="' . UPFW_UPLOADS_URL . "/" . $file . '" /></a>';

    endwhile;

    $list .= '<div class="clear"></div>';

    echo $list;

    closedir($dir_handle);
    die();

}

/**
 * Get current template context
 * 
 * Returns a string containing the context of the
 * current page template. This string is useful for several
 * purposes, including applying an ID to the HTML
 * body tag, and adding a contextual $name to calls
 * to get_header(), get_footer(), get_sidebar(), 
 * and get_template_part_file(), in order to 
 * facilitate Child Themes overriding default Theme
 * template part files.
 * 
 * @param   none
 * @return  string  current page template context
 */
function upfw_get_template_context() {

    $context = 'index';

    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        // Front Page
        $context = 'front-page';
    } else if ( is_date() ) {
        // Date Archive Index
        $context = 'date';
    } else if ( is_author() ) {
        // Author Archive Index
        $context = 'author';
    } else if ( is_category() ) {
        // Category Archive Index
        $context = 'category';
    } else if ( is_tag() ) {
        // Tag Archive Index
        $context = 'tag';
    } else if ( is_tax() ) {
        // Taxonomy Archive Index
        $context = 'taxonomy';
    } else if ( is_archive() ) {
        // Archive Index
        $context = 'archive';
    } else if ( is_search() ) {
        // Search Results Page
        $context = 'search';
    } else if ( is_404() ) {
        // Error 404 Page
        $context = '404';
    } else if ( is_attachment() ) {
        // Attachment Page
        $context = 'attachment';
    } else if ( is_single() ) {
        // Single Blog Post
        $context = 'single';
    } else if ( is_page() ) {
        // Static Page
        $context = 'page';
    } else if ( is_home() ) {
        // Blog Posts Index
        $context = 'home';
    }

    return $context;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_show_gallery_images','show_gallery_images');

/******
** Create Framework Options Pages
*************************************/
function upfw_create_options_tabs(){

    // Discover Options Files and Create Tabs Array
    if( is_admin() ):
        $path = THEME_PATH."/theme-options/";
        $directory = @opendir($path) or wp_die("Cannot open theme-options folder in the ".UPTHEMES_NAME." folder.");
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($directory))) {
            if(!preg_match('/_/', $file)) continue;
            if(preg_match('/_notes/', $file)) continue;
            if(preg_match('/.DS/', $file)) continue;

            //Take the extension off
            $file = explode('.php', $file);

            //Separate the ordinal
            $file = explode('_', $file[0]);
            $order = $file[1];
            //Define the shortname
            $shortname = $file[0];

            //Define the title
            $file = explode('-', $shortname);
            $title = '';
            foreach ($file as $part):
                $title .= $part." ";
            endforeach;
            $title = ucwords($title);

            //Add tab to array
            global $up_tabs;
            $up_tabs[$order] =  array(trim($title) => $shortname);
            $title = '';
        }
        closedir($directory);

        //Sort tab order
        global $up_tabs;
        ksort($up_tabs);
    endif;

}

add_action('upfw_admin_init','upfw_create_options_tabs',50);

/******
** Install default theme options
** if not already set
*************************************/
function upfw_set_defaults(){

    if( ! get_option( 'up_themes_'.UPTHEMES_SHORT_NAME) && ( ! isset( $_GET['page'] ) || 'proframework' != $_GET['page'] ) ) :

        //Redirect to options page where defaults will automatically be set
        header('Location: '.get_bloginfo('url').'/wp-admin/admin.php?page=proframework');
        exit;

    endif;

}

add_action('upfw_theme_activation', 'upfw_set_defaults',2);

/******
** Set up global theme options
*************************************/
function upfw_setup_theme_options(){

    $up_options_db = get_option('up_themes_'.UPTHEMES_SHORT_NAME);

    global $up_options;

    //Check if options are stored properly
    if( isset($up_options_db) && is_array($up_options_db) ):


add_action('upfw_theme_init','upfw_setup_theme_options',100);
add_action('upfw_admin_init','upfw_setup_theme_options',100);

/******
** Bootstrap static framework pages
*************************************/
function upthemes_admin_home() {require_once('home.php');}
function upthemes_admin_docs(){require_once('docs.php');}

/******
** Activate Pro Affiliate Framework admin
*************************************/
function upfw_upthemes_admin() {

    $name = __('My Options', MOJO_TEXTDOMAIN);

    $theme_options_icon = apply_filters('theme_options_icon',THEME_DIR.'/includes/pro_framework/images/upfw_ico_up_16x16.png');

    add_menu_page($name, $name, 'edit_theme_options', 'proframework', 'upthemes_admin_home', $theme_options_icon, 59);

    //Create tabbed pages from array
    global $up_tabs;
    if( is_array( $up_tabs ) ):
        foreach ($up_tabs as $tab):
            foreach($tab as $title => $shortname):
                add_submenu_page('proframework', $title, $title, 'edit_theme_options', 'proframework#/'.$shortname, 'upthemes_admin_'.$shortname);
            endforeach;
        endforeach;
    endif;

    //Static subpages
    // add_submenu_page('proframework', __('Documentation', MOJO_TEXTDOMAIN), __('Documentation', MOJO_TEXTDOMAIN), 'edit_theme_options', 'proframework-docs', 'upthemes_admin_docs');

}

add_action('admin_menu', 'upfw_upthemes_admin',2);

/******
** Find default options
*************************************/
function find_defaults($options){
    global $up_defaults;
    print_r($options);
}

/******
** Render theme options
*************************************/
function render_options($options){

    //Check if theme options set
    global $default_check;
    global $default_options;
    global $attr;
    $attr = '';

    if(!$default_check):
        foreach($options as $option):
            if($option['type'] != 'image'):
                $default_options[$option['id']] = $option['value'];
            else:
                $default_options[$option['id']] = $option['url'];
            endif;
        endforeach;
        $update_option = get_option('up_themes_'.UPTHEMES_SHORT_NAME);
        if(is_array($update_option)):
            $update_option = array_merge($update_option, $default_options);
            update_option('up_themes_'.UPTHEMES_SHORT_NAME, $update_option);
        else:
            update_option('up_themes_'.UPTHEMES_SHORT_NAME, $default_options);
        endif;
    endif;

    foreach ($options as $value) {
        //Check if there are additional attributes
        if ( isset( $value['attr'] ) && is_array( $value['attr'] ) ):
            $i = $value['attr'];
            //Convert array into a string
            foreach($i as $k => $v):
                $attr .= $k.'="'.$v.'" ';
            endforeach;
        endif;

        //Determine the type of input field
        switch ( $value['type'] ) {

            //Render Text Input
            case 'text': upfw_text_field($value,$attr);
            break;

            //Render Custom User Text Inputs
            case 'text_list': upfw_text_list($value,$attr);
            break;

            //Render textarea options
            case 'textarea': upfw_textarea($value,$attr);
            break;

            //Render select dropdowns
            case 'select': upfw_select($value,$attr);
            break;

            //Render multple selects
            case 'multiple': upfw_multiple($value,$attr);
            break;

            //Render checkboxes
            case 'checkbox': upfw_checkbox($value,$attr);
            break;

            //Render color picker
            case 'color': upfw_color($value,$attr);
            break;

            //Render upload image
            case 'image': upfw_image($value,$attr);
            break;

            //Render upload image
            case 'logo': upfw_logo($value,$attr);
            break;

            //Render category dropdown
            case 'category': upfw_category($value,$attr);
            break;

            //Render categories multiple select
            case 'categories': upfw_categories($value,$attr);
            break;

            //Render offer dropdown
            case 'offer': upfw_offer($value,$attr);
            break;

            //Render sales letter dropdown
            case 'sales_letter': upfw_sales_letter($value,$attr);
            break;

            //Render squeeze page dropdown
            case 'squeeze': upfw_squeeze($value,$attr);
            break;

            //Render page dropdown
            case 'page': upfw_page($value,$attr);
            break;

            //Render pages muliple select
            case 'pages': upfw_pages($value,$attr);
            break;

            //Render Form Button
            case 'submit': upfw_submit($value,$attr);
            break;

            //Render taxonomy multiple select
            case 'taxonomy': upfw_taxonomy($value,$attr);
            break;

            //Render Style Selector
            case 'styles': upfw_style($value,$attr);
            break;

            //Render Form Button
            case 'button': upfw_button($value,$attr);
            break;

            //Render Text Input
            case 'divider': upfw_divider($value,$attr);
            break;

            //Render Layouts
            case 'layouts': upfw_layouts($value,$attr);
            break;

            default:
            break;
        }
        $attr = '';
    }
}

if(is_admin() && is_upthemes_page()) add_action( 'upfw_admin_init','upfw_save_options', 3 );

function upfw_save_options(){

    /* ----------------------- Form Security Check -------------------------- */
    if(isset($_POST['_wpnonce'])):
        //Check if submitted from this domain
        check_admin_referer();

        //Verify Form Nonce
        if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['_wpnonce'], 'save_upthemes') ) 
            wp_die('Security exception detected, please try again.');
            exit;
    endif;

    /* ------------------Import/Export Functions ----------------------- */
    //Restore Previous Options
    global $export_message;
    if(isset($_POST['up_restore'])):
        $current = get_option('up_themes_'.UPTHEMES_SHORT_NAME);
        $backup = get_option('up_themes_'.UPTHEMES_SHORT_NAME.'_backup');
        update_option('up_themes_'.UPTHEMES_SHORT_NAME.'_backup', $current);
        update_option('up_themes_'.UPTHEMES_SHORT_NAME, $backup);
        $export_message = "<p class='import'>" . __("Everything's back to normal now!", MOJO_TEXTDOMAIN) . "</p>";
    endif;

    //Restore Defaults

    if(isset($_POST['up_defaults'])):
        $current = get_option('up_themes_'.UPTHEMES_SHORT_NAME);
        update_option('up_themes_'.UPTHEMES_SHORT_NAME.'_backup', $current);
        delete_option('up_themes_'.UPTHEMES_SHORT_NAME);
        $export_message = "<p class='import'>" . __("Default options restored!", MOJO_TEXTDOMAIN) . "<span><form method='post' action=''><input class='up_restore' type='submit' name='up_restore' value='" . __("Click Here to Undo", MOJO_TEXTDOMAIN) . "'></form></span></p>";
    endif;

    /* ------------------------- Import Options Code ------------------------------- */
    if(isset($_POST['up_import']) && isset($_POST['up_import_code'])):
        $import = $_POST['up_import_code'];
        $import = base64_decode($import);
        $import = explode('~~', $import);

        //Check if code is legitimate
        if(count($import) == 2):
            $option_name = $import[0];
            $options = explode('||', $import[1]);

            foreach ($options as $option):
                $option = explode('|', $option);
                global $new_options;
                $new_options[$option[0]] = preg_replace('/"/', '\'', stripslashes($option[1]));
            endforeach;
            $current_option = get_option($option_name);
            update_option($option_name.'_backup', $current_option);
            update_option($option_name, $new_options);
            $export_message = "<p class='import'>" . __("Options Code Import Successful!", MOJO_TEXTDOMAIN) . "<span><form method='post' action=''><input class='up_restore' type='submit' name='up_restore' value='" . __("Click Here to Undo", MOJO_TEXTDOMAIN) . "'></form></span></p>";
        else:
            $export_message = "<p class='import'>" . __("Oops! Something went wrong. <span>Try pasting your import code again.</span>", MOJO_TEXTDOMAIN) . "</p>";
        endif;

    endif;

    /* ------------------------- Save Theme Options ------------------------------- */
    if(isset($_POST['up_save'])):

            $posts = $_POST;
            foreach($posts as $k => $v):
                //Check if option is array (mulitple selects)
                if(is_array($v)):
                    //Check if array is empty
                    $check = 0;
                    foreach($v as $key => $value):    
                        if($value != ''):
                            $check++;
                        endif;
                    endforeach;
                    //If array is not empty
                    if($check > 0  ):
                        //Remove empty array elements
                        $post[$k] = array_filter($v);
                    else:
                        $post[$k] = '';
                    endif;
                    $check = 0;
                else:
                    //Remove slashes
                    $post[$k] = preg_replace('/"/', '\'', stripslashes($v));
                endif;
            endforeach;
            //Add options array to wp_options table
            update_option('up_themes_'.UPTHEMES_SHORT_NAME, $post);
        endif;

    /* ---------------------- Default Options Functions  ----------------- */
    global $default_check;
    global $default_options;

    $option_check = get_option('up_themes_'.UPTHEMES_SHORT_NAME);   
    if($option_check):
        $default_check = true;
    else:
        $default_check = false;
    endif;

}

/******
** Remove Ugly First Link in 
** WP Sidebar Menu
*************************************/

function remove_ugly_first_link(){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('li#toplevel_page_upthemes li.wp-first-item').remove();
    });
    </script>
<?php }

if( is_admin() )
    add_action("admin_head","remove_ugly_first_link"); 

/******
** RSS URL: rss('return') will return 
** the value and not echo it.
*************************************/
function upfw_rss($i = ''){
    global $up_options;
    if($up_options->feedburner):
        $rss = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/".$up_options->feedburner;
    else:
        $rss = get_bloginfo_rss('rss2_url');
    endif;
    if($i == 'return'): return $rss; else: echo $rss; endif;
}

/******
** RSS Subscribe URL: rss_email('return') 
** will return the value and not echo it.
*************************************/
function upfw_rss_email($i = ''){
    global $up_options;
    if($up_options->feedburner):
        $rssemail = "http://www.feedburner.com/fb/a/emailverifySubmit?feedId=" . $up_options->feedburner;
    else:
        $rssemail = "#";
    endif;
    if($i == 'return'): return $rssemail; else: echo $rssemail; endif;
}

/******
** Admin header hook
*************************************/
function upfw_admin_header(){
    do_action('upfw_admin_header');
}

/******
** Open admin header
*************************************/
function upfw_admin_header_open(){ ?>
    <div id="up_header" class="polish"><?php
}

add_action('upfw_admin_header','upfw_admin_header_open',1);

/******
** Set admin header title
*************************************/
function upfw_admin_header_title(){ ?>
    <div id="icon-upfw" class="icon32 icon32-upfw"></div>
    <h2><?php _e("", MOJO_TEXTDOMAIN); ?></h2> <?php
}

add_action('upfw_admin_header','upfw_admin_header_title',100);

/******
** Create admin header links
*************************************/
function upfw_admin_header_links(){ ?>
    <ul id="up_topnav">
        <?php do_action('upfw_admin_header_links'); ?>
    </ul><!-- /#up_topnav --><?php
}

add_action('upfw_admin_header','upfw_admin_header_links',50);

/******
** Close admin header
*************************************/
function upfw_admin_header_close(){ ?>

            <div class="clear"></div>

        </div><!-- /#up_header --><?php

}

add_action('upfw_admin_header','upfw_admin_header_close',500);

/******
** Add default header links
*************************************/
function upfw_default_header_links(){ ?>

    <li class="documentation"><a href="http://www.mojo-themes.com/item/betty-woocommerce-wordpress-theme/" target="_blank"><?php _e("MOJO-Themes Item Page", MOJO_TEXTDOMAIN); ?></a></li>
    <li class="support"><a target="_blank" href="http://docs.mojoness.com/"><?php _e("Support", MOJO_TEXTDOMAIN); ?></a></li>
    <?php   

}

add_action('upfw_admin_header_links','upfw_default_header_links');
```

Comment: what is this `}` for ??

Comment: That is closing an element above I believe, that line I have attached is the bottom line of code

Comment: Can you paste you file content here(as it is) ?? [http://pastebin.com/](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: It's too big to post. I will add into the top first post I made now.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7XNP6CwC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry , just add `?>` at last.

try to change it to

```
add_action('upfw_admin_header','upfw_admin_header_links',50);
```

[Holding-Pattern-Theme](https://github.com/LiftUX/Holding-Pattern-Theme/blob/master/admin/admin.php)

Comment: Still showing the same error! I think it may be something else in the page which is corrupting it

Comment: @AlfieGreen add ?> beind add_action('upfw_admin_header','upfw_admin_header_links',50); ?>

Comment: When I add ?> which I did think would solve it, the error jumps down to that line...

Comment: ?>  add_action('upfw_admin_header','upfw_admin_header_links',50); ?>
Error is still showing.

Comment: @AlfieGreen you didn't change any thing..so maybe it is an encode problem. I advise you that can download files of the themes. then replace this error file..

Comment: I have theme files, however I have done a clean install and the problem persists.

Comment: @AlfieGreen It looks like that your problem has been solved..your website is normal. some warning messages .you can refer to http://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/12/php-warning-missing-argument-2-for-wpdb-prepare/ to disable warning..

Comment: Thank you very much for  your help. Collectively it has resolved the issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a missing `}` for `function upfw_setup_theme_options()` declaration (line 411).
EDIT:

```
function upfw_setup_theme_options(){

$up_options_db = get_option('up_themes_'.UPTHEMES_SHORT_NAME);

global $up_options;

//Check if options are stored properly
if( isset($up_options_db) && is_array($up_options_db) ):
# missing part start
//Check array to an object
foreach ($up_options_db as $k => $v) {
$up_options -> {$k} = $v;
}

else:

do_action('upfw_theme_activation');

endif;

}
#missing part end
```

from https://github.com/LiftUX/Holding-Pattern-Theme/blob/master/admin/admin.php

Comment: Thank you, I see... so where does the missing } need to go?

Comment: there is also a missing endif, do you have any backup of this file?

Answer (score 0):

This error was happening on my local env but not on other's computers

Make sure you close the PHP tag correctly:

```
<?php } ?>
```

In my particular case:

```
<?php if( $condition ){ ?>
  <div> content </div>
<? } ?>
```

That last block: `<? } ?>` was missing the `?php` close tag.